# RecyclerView of RecyclerViews: Image Loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-image

I try to implement a layout that contains a vertical `RecyclerView` that itself contains multiple horizontal `RecyclerViews` (imagine a news site, with multiple news sections, where each section contains multiple news stories that can be scrolled horizontally).

The horizontal `RecyclerView` contains (among other things) an `ImageView`. I'm looking for the optimal strategy of loading an image from an URL into this `ImageView`.

Firstly, my code. The Adapter for the outer RecyclerView:

```
    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_preview_list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);

        mh.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, listener, new ArrayList<ContentPreviewButtonItem>()));
        mh.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {
        Log.d("RecyclerViewDataAdapter", "onBindViewHolder");
        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getItems();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);
         ((SectionListDataAdapter)itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.getAdapter()).setItemList(singleSectionItems);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
```

And for the inner RecyclerView that contains the images:

```
    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Log.d("SectionListDataAdapter", "onCreateViewHolder");
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_preview_item, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        Log.d("SectionListDataAdapter", "onBindViewHolder");
        ContentPreviewButtonItem singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(singleItem.getImageUrl());
        holder.itemImage.setImageURI(imageUri); //itemImage is a SimpleDraweeView

    }
```

While this code works great on mobile, there's a noticeable lag on tablet when multiple inner `RecyclerViews` and images are loaded at once. Right now I use Facebook's Fresco library to load the image into a `SimpleDraweeView`. I also tried Picasso but that yield an `OutOfMemoryException` when multiple images had to be loaded at once. 
I improved the performance by moving the adapter creation of the inner `RecyclerViews` into the `onCreateViewHolder` instead of the `onBindViewHolder`, but the lag is still noticeable.

What's the best strategy or library to load images in this scenario.
Thanks

Comment: Glide is a perfect fit for this I believe using which you can resize the image also while the image is loading you can display a thumbnail of the same

Comment: You can to the same thing using Picasso. I'm not sure I can expect a performance improvement from using Glide. Or is there a reason you would recommend Glide instead of Picasso, Fresco etc.?

Comment: I'm using glide for a long time now and it's caching and large image handling ability is really astonishing

Comment: Looks good. So far, no lag. No OutOfMemoryExceptions either. Thanks! Images seem to load a bit slower than when using Fresco. Do you know a strategy to speed up the loading process? Cheers.

Comment: You can decrease image size a bit orelse use thumbnail which will load the image in bg meanwhile it will show a small pic of it

Answer (score 0):

Glide is a perfect fit for this I believe using which you can resize the image also while the image is loading you can display a thumbnail of the same

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same in my project and so far the best service I got is from [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. Their resizing capabilities are the best. Might be a little slow on first load but subsequent loading is super fast.